# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in ejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, object, ejs

Below is my code,am accessing server object in variable but throws following error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in ejs

```
routerfile.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res) { 
       var obj ={"cn": "TH", "about": {"name": "thailand"}}
       res.render('index.ejs', {res: obj});
})

util.js
var x = <%= JSON.parse(res) %>; //throws unexpect token error

index.ejs
<a href ="/en/<%=JSON.parse(res.about[name])%>">click me</a> // throws name not defined.
```

Comment: chances are your server is giving you HTML, which isn't JSON

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for reply, is there any possibility to get json data

Comment: you get what the server sends

Comment: @JaromandaX Its because rendering page along with json data